# "Migrations" -- sender account not recognized

Tags: metamask, ethereum-wallet-dapp, dapp-development, infura, ganache-cli

This is my truffle.js i've removed the credentials marked as *

```
var HDWalletProvider = require('@truffle/hdwallet-provider');
var fs = require('fs');
var infura_apikey = "*"
var mnemonic = "*";
var address = "*"

module.exports = {
  // See <http://truffleframework.com/docs/advanced/configuration>
  // for more about customizing your Truffle configuration!
  solc: {
    optimizer: {
      enabled: true,
      runs: 200
      
           
    }
  },
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "*" // Match any network id
    },
    ropsten: {
      provider: function() {
        return new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, "https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/*", 3)
      },
      network_id: 3,
      from: address,
      gas: 4700388
    }
  }

};
```

When I'm trying to migrate my contracts "Migrations.sol" & "CertiVerify.sol"
The error is:

```
1_initial_migration.js
======================

   Deploying 'Migrations'
   ----------------------

Error:  *** Deployment Failed ***

"Migrations" -- sender account not recognized.

    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/deployer/src/deployment.js:364:1
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at Migration._deploy (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/migration.js:70:1)
    at Migration._load (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/migration.js:57:1)
    at Migration.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/migration.js:173:1)
    at Object.runMigrations (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/index.js:148:1)
    at Object.runFrom (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/index.js:110:1)
    at Object.runAll (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/index.js:114:1)
    at Object.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/index.js:79:1)
    at runMigrations (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/commands/migrate.js:253:1)
    at setupDryRunEnvironmentThenRunMigrations (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/commands/migrate.js:241:1)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/commands/migrate.js:207:1
```

Migrations.sol:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Migrations {
  address public owner;
  uint public last_completed_migration;

  modifier restricted() {
    if (msg.sender == owner) _;
  }

  constructor() public {
    owner = msg.sender;
  }

  function setCompleted(uint completed) public restricted {
    last_completed_migration = completed;
  }

  function upgrade(address new_address) public restricted {
    Migrations upgraded = Migrations(new_address);
    upgraded.setCompleted(last_completed_migration);
  }
}
```

1_intial_migrations.js

```
var Migrations = artifacts.require("./Migrations.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Migrations);
};
```

I do not know what exactly is the error here. Can anyone help me out with it and guide me on how do I use Metamask, Infura, Ropsten & Ganace in this application and what keys do I need to place on the '*' .

Answer (score -1):

- Run `development` network:

```
truffle console --network development
```

*NOTE:* Start `Ganache` first

- Run `ropsten` network:

```
truffle console --network ropsten
```

*NOTE:* Do not use the `from` in the  *truffle.js* to deploy from account[0].

Comment: Well, actually using the `from` field in truffle.js is useful if you want to deploy contracts from a specific address. Im having the same problem and I have an actual need to use the from field.